# Ambari server host registration failed for single hosts (current machine) on which ambari service is running

Tags: ambari, hdp

Ambari 2.5.1.0 / centOS-7 -> Ambari agent, Ambari server running with an external postgres9.6 database on same system.

Now, hit Ambari url ->
login to Ambari -> Create a cluster -> provide cluster name -> next
selecet HDP-2.6.3.0 -> select 'use public repository' -> select redhat7 OS -> next
Enter only one hostname / FQDN of current centOS-7 machine.
Select 'Perform manual registration on hosts and do not use SSH'
Now Click 'Register and Confirm' button

Result: "status - failed" with message "Host checks were skipped on 1 hosts that failed to register."

Comment: You should start with checking `/var/log/ambari-*/*.log` files to see why registration failed

Comment: ambari-agent log helped, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I added following line in ambari-con.ini in etc/ambari-agent/conf directory under "security"
force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2